# build a single output with CodeSmith csp

Tags: codesmith

CodeSmith project files (csp) allow multiple outputs defined and run together.
I would like to re-generate only a single output from the command line the way the UI allows.
Is there a command line switch to cs.exe I'm missing that will allow me to target a single propertySet in the csp file?

Answer (score 1):

There is no command line switch to cs.exe that allows this. You have to roll your own.

`CodeSmith.Engine.Schema.CodeSmithProject` has static method `LoadFile(string)` and property `PropertySets`.

The `CodeSmith.Engine.CodeTemplate.RestorePropertiesFromPropertySet(PropertySet, baseDirectory)` method allows you populate the Properties on a `CodeTemplate` instance.

Tie this together with the SDK sample for instantiating and executing a `CodeTemplate` https://codesmith.atlassian.net/wiki/display/Generator/Using+the+Generator+SDK.